# Modern Warfare 2 multiplayer accuracy stats hacked

Tags: xbox-360, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

How did my online accuracy stats get hacked (reads negative percentage)?

It seems it's the only stat to get hacked over KDR and Wins, etc.

Not a big deal, I have 1.4 million misses so I'm not very accurate anyway (extended mag on RPD doesn't help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Modern Warfare 2 leader boards are notorious for being hacked.  Also, IW has offered little support for trying to resolve the issue and verified that it is tedious process to try to clean up the leader boards.

Your best bet is to just wait for the release of MW3.

Comment: I see, thanks. MW3 leader boards will be more stable I presume?

Comment: With the focus on COD Elite, they are trying to make COD a social experience.  Here is a link for more info: http://www.callofduty.com/elite

Comment: OK, will checkout, not sure if I'm going to pay for elite service, curious to see if the good players go that way but that's off topic, thanks.

Comment: COD elite also offers a free membership.  If you plan on purchasing DLCs for MW3, then the paid service is worth it because the DLCs are included with your enrollment fee ($49.99 USD per year)

Comment: Right, yah I do get all the map packs so might as well be worth it, cheers